# What do the `String` keys for the `Map<String,ISuiteResult>` returned by `ISuite.getResults()` in TestNG represent?

Tags: java, testng

I'm writing a `TestSuiteLogger` implementation for `ISuiteListener` in TestNG. I'm trying to write out a statement about the results for the `onFinish(ISuite suite)` method.

There is a `getResults()` method defined on the `ISuite interface` that returns a `Map<String,ISuiteResult>` and the javadoc doesn't explain what the `String` keys represent. What are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This string parameter is the name of suite for which you want to get result
you can verify it by this code

```
   public void onFinish(ISuite isuite) {
        Map<String , ISuiteResult>  result =     isuite.getResults();
        Set<String> suites = result.keySet();
        for (String string : suites) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I figured out that it's a 'name' attribute for a test consisting of a bunch of `classes` from the `XML` file. It threw me off because `ISuite` doesn't have an accessor for test names, but it does for test methods.